# The changes you requested to the table were not successful

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, primary-key

Before anyone starts shouting "duplicate", let me say that I've searched for a solution to this problem thoroughly, and found no solutions.

Background info: I'm attempting to inset into a small table in an Access 2003 database from a compiled windows form program (exe) made with Visual Basic 2010 Express.

There are four insert statements performed in this same database, each on a different table, but the first three work without issue, it's the fourth one that throws the error:

```
cmd = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO PrivateTableName 
                        VALUES('" & Serial.Text & "','Pending',
                               '" & coverArea.Text & "','')", myConnection)
Try
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Catch ex As Exception
     MsgBox("Error attempting to insert into PrivateTableName " & ex.ToString)
     Exit Sub
End Try
```

I've changed the name of the table for privacy purposes, but rest assured, the table name is irrelevant.

This statement throws the exception

> The changes you requested to the table were not successful because they would create duplicate values in the index, primary key, or relationship

The error itself is pretty self-explanatory, yet, utterly impossible. Below is a screen shot of the table design

[image: table design]

Note that the primary key is not an auto incrementing number. The primary key is a serial number (or rather a string) which is consists of a 5 digit number (which is sequentially indexed from the previous) and two letters which are randomly generated (i.e. 14582KH), and I've verified that the value it attempts to insert as the primary key doesn't already exist.

I've already tried to compact and repair the database, which didn't help.  There are no relationships between the fields in this table with fields in other tables, it's completely independent.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is nothing is obvious then reset your expectations. You say "yet, utterly impossible": it appears your db disagrees: you are doing something wrong, review, check and check again every assumption (including those you've forgotten and need to re-remember).

Comment: Your insert seems to be text, text, text but your table is text, text, number, text. It would be much safer to list the fields /columns in the insert statement. Furthermore, you should use parameters.

Comment: ok, I've edited the question, it did throw the exception from the compiler, but not consistently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I'm unsure why it matters, specifying the fields seems to fix the problem.

```
cmd = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO PrivateTableName ([My Order Number],
[BV Order Number], [Area]) VALUES('" & Serial.Text & _ "','Pending'," &
coverArea.Text & ")", myConnection)
```

Comment: The problem `INSERT` included 4 `VALUES` --- the fourth was an empty string. This working version inserts 3 `VALUES`. There is a clue hidden in there.

Comment: yes, I didn't see the use in specifying a field only to insert a null value.  I don't see what you're getting at.  I had to use 4 values before because I didn't bother specifying feilds.  INSERT INTO PrivateTableName ([My Order Number],
[BV Order Number], [Area], [Job ID]) VALUES('" & Serial.Text & _ "','Pending'," &
coverArea.Text & ",'')", myConnection) also works.

Comment: OK, I was speculating the problem might have been due to the null string for *Job ID*.  But you've demonstrated that was not the problem.  In that case the explanation is that without explicitly listing the destination fields, your failed `INSERT` was not matching values to fields in the order you expected.  Specifying the fields avoids that problem.

Answer (score 1):

The area column has a datatype Number, but your insert a string into it, by using

```
"'" & coverArea.Text & "'"
```

You should create the command as:

```
cmd = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO PrivateTableName VALUES('" & 
 Serial.Text & 
 "','Pending'," 
 & coverArea.Text 
 & ",'')", myConnection)
```

I can't imagine this will work in debug mode. Only when you run the INSERT statement directly against the database where you probably would use the correct syntax.

A better and safer approach would be to use [DbParameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: thanks, but that didn't solve the problem.  Same error

Comment: what is exception you get?

Comment: System.Data.OleDbException (0x80004005)

Comment: Ok, I've got it.  Specifying the fields seems to fix the problem   cmd = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO PrivateTableName ([My Order Number], [BV Order Number], [Area]) VALUES('" & Serial.Text & _
                                                            "','Pending'," & coverArea.Text & ")", myConnection)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should check if is there any field wrong. If not choose yes (duplicate OK) or No.

[image]

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer, or just post it as a comment to the question).

Comment: I don't see what value you think you're adding.  This question was asked more that 3 years ago, and clearly already has a solution.